# Setting output path on a per user basis

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I want to set the output path for all binary files in a .NET solution in VS2012 to another location on a per user basis.

I found that I can modify the .csproj.user file manually so that it includes a line like

```
<OutputPath>C:\exe\MyApp\Debugx86</OutputPath>
```

And this redirects the output of my main application to the new output folder. But as soon as I do this there are two problems:

1. Clean solution doesn't delete the output files anymore
2. I can't start debugger, because it expects the exe at the old location.

So my question is: Is it possible to tell VS2012 to put the binary files to a different location, based on the users preferences who compiles the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Would you be amenable to having the output built in the same place for all users, and then having the build command copy the output to a different directory on a per-user basis? If so, you can add a post-build command to the primary project file, something like:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <YourSourceDirectory>..\SomeSourceDirectory</YourSourceDirectory>
        <YourDestinationDirectory>..\SomeDestinationDirectory</YourDestinationDirectory>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(YourFilesToCopy)" DestinationFiles="@(YourFilesToCopy->'$(YourDestinationDirectory)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Very interesting, but doesn't help me, because the goal is to keep the source directory small. So I don't want a copy the files somewhere else, I want to build these files in another location directly. Deleting the files at @(YourFilesToCopy) after copy would also not help, because this would result in a rebuild on every build.